# Can I use "Tell Us Once" to notify various UK Government departments for a death in Australia?

Tags: australia, uk-citizens, paperwork

The UK has quite a nice service ["Tell Us Once"](https://www.gov.uk/after-a-death/organisations-you-need-to-contact-and-tell-us-once) that lets you notify a whole bunch of Government departments about the death of someone.

On the [Gov.UK Death Abroad page](https://www.gov.uk/after-a-death/death-abroad), it says that the *Tell Us Once* service is available for deaths abroad in:

> You can use Tell Us Once if the person died in:
>
> - a Commonwealth country
> - a European Economic Area (EEA) country
> - Switzerland

So, based on that, it ought to work for a death of a UK citizen who has emigrated to and died in Australia (which is a Commonwealth country).

.

When I [go to use the Tell Us Once service online](https://idp-tell-us-someone-died.dwp.gov.uk/Death/Enrich/BeforeYouStart), it tells me I need a 12 character reference issued by the UK registrar before I can use the service.

Using the [prepare to register a death wizard on Gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/register-a-death/y/overseas/australia):

> You can’t register the death with the UK authorities. The death certificate you are given in Australia will be accepted and recognised in the UK.

So, it seems I can't use the *Tell Us Once* system without a magic reference code, only available when you register the death with the UK authorities, but I can't get one as the UK won't let you register a death in Australia with them...

.

Am I missing something here? Is there some way to get a reference code to use from the registrar in Australia (Queensland in case it helps)? Or is [Gov.UK Death Abroad page](https://www.gov.uk/after-a-death/death-abroad) wrong, with the service only available from certain Commonwealth Countries but not all?

Comment: I tried your link using another Commonwealth country at random (Barbados) and got a different response to the one you’ve posted, indicating that Tell Us Once is only available from some Commonwealth countries. However, the response also said “The service to register a death with the UK authorities is currently suspended. This page will be updated when it has resumed.” https://www.gov.uk/register-a-death/y/overseas/barbados/same_country